# Sql file is throwing errors when importing, but used to work fine

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I was woring on a project last year, and was exporting and importing fine, but recently I decided to import my sql file and I cannot import due to lots of errors in each table.

I deleted xampp once I stopped working on it, and now decided to download it again, but am stuck on import, here is my full file:

http://pastebin.com/mddVUU1i

My error is the following:

> CREATE TABLE `company_type` (   `company_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `company_type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,   `company_type_date` datetime
>   NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,   `company_type_enabled`
>   varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'enabled' ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT
>   CHARSET=latin1 MySQL said: Documentation
>
> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near '-----------------------------------------
>
> CREATE TABLE `company_type` (   `comp' at line 1

But when I delete that, I get another error:

> CREATE TABLE `employees` (   `employees_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `employees_page` int(11) NOT NULL,   `employees_page_type` varchar(15)
>   NOT NULL,   `employees_user` int(11) NOT NULL,   `employees_date`
>   datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,   `employees_manage`
>   varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'sent' ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT
>   CHARSET=latin1 MySQL said: Documentation
>
> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near '-----------------------------------------
>
> ------------------------------------' at line 1

How can I fix this? I have ran the sql through checkers online, and it state'sthe sql is fine.

Comment: Which MariaDB version are you using and which phpMyAdmin version as well?

Comment: Server version: 10.1.19-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution

Comment: phpmyadmin: 4.5.1

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong, either. Here are a few ideas to try: Copy and paste the file in to the SQL tab of phpMyAdmin, then see if it flags anything with a syntax error (with a small red circle/box on the left side of the text). Try importing at the command line and see if the problem continues. Try updating your phpMyAdmin to a more recent version; there have been some fixes for MariaDB compatibility since 4.5.1, though I'm not aware of any directly related to what you're seeing here.

Answer (score 0):

Your table creation is wrong, you are misplacing datetime data-type to timestamp values.

Here is your first erroneous table

```
CREATE TABLE company_type (  company_type_id int(11) NOT NULL,
company_type varchar(50) NOT NULL,  company_type_date datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  company_type_enabled varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'enabled' ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The problem here is
**datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP**

You are using datetime datatype to timestamp values.

if you want to use **timestamp** datatype then do it this way

```
CREATE TABLE employees (  employees_id int(11) NOT NULL,
employees_page int(11) NOT NULL,  employees_page_type varchar(15) NOT NULL, employees_user int(11) NOT NULL, 
 employees_date timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  
employees_manage varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'sent' ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

if you want to use **datetime** datatype then do it this way

```
CREATE TABLE employees1 (  employees_id int(11) NOT NULL,
employees_page int(11) NOT NULL,  employees_page_type varchar(15) NOT NULL, employees_user int(11) NOT NULL, 
 employees_date datetime NOT NULL, 
 employees_manage varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'sent' ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```